# Fetch the values from a string with regular expression in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string and I want to extract the needed values from this string, so I wrote some regex patterns, I searched in google and I find I have to use `echo` command and then store in a variable.

I tested my regex pattern with regex101.com and the pattern is correct but I don't know why not work in bash script.

this is my code:

```
output="VPC created: vpc-something
Security Group created: sg-something
Subnet created: subnet-something1
Subnet created: subnet-something2
Cluster creation succeeded."


regex1="/(VPC\screated:)\s+(.*)$/gm"
regex2="/(Subnet\screated:)\s+(.*)$/gm"

vpc=$(echo $output| grep -q $regex1)
subnet=$(echo $output| grep -q $regex2)

echo $vpc
echo $subnet
```

the output of this code is nothing

Comment: Do you have a GNU `grep`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know, I run this script on my MacBook

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the `grep` command work on my machine

Comment: You can check that with `grep --version` I think, at least mine displays multiple lines the first of which is `grep (GNU grep) 3.0`

Comment: @Aaron the output of `grep --version` is `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`, so I cannot use regex ?

Comment: What is expected for the subnet? You may use regex. Check https://ideone.com/rpyYbS. Remove `head -1 |` to get all subnets

Comment: You still can use regexes, but you won't have GNU-specific grep features. I'm not quite sure which Wiktor was thinking about.

Comment: Does my suggestion work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, your code worked, about the `subnet` might we have one or more than one line subnet, can I get all lines ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
output="VPC created: vpc-something
Security Group created: sg-something
Subnet created: subnet-something1
Subnet created: subnet-something2
Cluster creation succeeded."


regex1="VPC +created:.*"
regex2="Subnet +created:.*"

vpc="$(echo "$output" | grep -Eo "$regex1" | sed -E 's/VPC +created: *//')"
subnet="$(echo "$output"| grep -Eo "$regex2" | sed -E 's/Subnet +created: *//')"

echo $vpc
for v in "$subnet"; do echo "$v"; done
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/AgkRJX), output:

```
vpc-something
subnet-something1
subnet-something2
```

**NOTE**

- The variables containing whitespace are in double quotation marks (or errors will pop)
- `regex1` and `regex2` are patterns that just match `VPC created:` and `Subnet created:` strings + all the rest of the lines, and these "prefixes" must be removed later with `sed` that is piped right after
- `-E` with both `grep` and `sed` enables the POSIX ERE syntax that is closer to the syntax used by the "modern" regex engines (it allows `+` quantifier)

  - `o`  `grep` option tells `grep` to output the *matched texts* and not the whole line where match occurred.

Comment: A side note - a little more detail on the `sed` makes the `grep` superfluous. `regex1="VPC +created: *";   sed -En "/$regex1/ { s/$regex1//; p; }" <<< "$output"`

Comment: If it weren't at the beginning we'd need to elaborate the regex for sure... but there isn't a lot that `grep` does that `sed` won't unless you start using `perl` patterns. There is some, admitted, but we can agree to disagree...or not. ;)  For the more robust structure, you might prefer another process to a harder to maintain set of patterns. That's fair.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` option `q` means "quiet", it prevents any output to STDOUT.

Does removing it fix your code?

Comment: No, it does not. Have you seen the regex patterns?